# React native issue with navigation"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

so I am really having a hard time with this navigation thing. I am not an expert in Js or react native, but since the person working on this app isn't in the company anymore, I am asked to make some tweaks here and there until a new person comes in but I am struggling with this navigation thing.

so I am using this to go to my two factor identification
any idea what does this navigate do anyway? how can I set it value? do it need to passe it somehow?

full code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Image,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native'
import {requiredFields} from '../helpers/forms'
import BusyButton from '../Common/BusyButton'
import DismissKeyboard from '../Common/DismissKeyboard'
import {Colors} from '../styles'
import LoginStyles from './LogInStyles'

const loginStyles = LoginStyles.createStyles()

/* eslint-disable camelcase,space-before-function-paren */
export default class TwoFactor extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    screenProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }

  state = {
    verificationCode: '',
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    try{
    const {screenProps: {auth: {sendVerificationCode}}, navigation: {navigate}} = this.props

    if (requiredFields(['verificationCode'], ['Verification Code'], this.state)) {
      sendVerificationCode(this.state.verificationCode,this.state.user, navigate)
    }

    return false
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {screenProps: {auth: {isFetching}}} = this.props


    return (
      <DismissKeyboard style={loginStyles.pageWrapper}>
        <View style={loginStyles.logoContainer}>
          <Image
            style={loginStyles.logo}
            resizeMode="contain"
            source={require('../../assets/images/logo-IH_blue_gold-small.png')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={loginStyles.containerExpand}>
          <Text style={loginStyles.h1}>ID Verification</Text>
          <Text style={loginStyles.label}>
            A verification code has been sent to the phone number on file. Please enter the code below.
          </Text>
          <TextInput
            style={loginStyles.input}
            placeholder="Verification Code"
            placeholderTextColor={Colors.lightGray}
            onChangeText={(verificationCode) => this.setState({verificationCode})}
            keyboardType="number-pad"
          />
        </View>
        <View style={loginStyles.container}>
          <View style={loginStyles.buttonContainer}>
            <BusyButton
              style={loginStyles.button}
              underlayColor={Colors.buttonPrimaryBkgd}
              isBusy={isFetching}
              onPress={this.handleSubmit}
            >
              <Text style={loginStyles.buttonText}>Next</Text>
            </BusyButton>
          </View>
        </View>
      </DismissKeyboard>
    )
  }
}
```

ERROR

```
it's not spitting any error, but it is not taking me to the next screen.
```

Comment: can you share the entire code and the error you are getting in an expo. iLl be able to help then. What i believe is you are importing the navigate thing wrong. just share the code. ill be able to help

Comment: yes, I update the post

Comment: can you explain to me the role of navigate in this line please ```  sendVerificationCode(this.state.verificationCode,this.state.user, navigate)```

Comment: see usually navigate is something to navigate to other screens , here i guess you are bringing navigate as props from previous screen and as send verification , you are calling that props which will navigate to other screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with Navigation in React Native - Organizing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700738/issue-with-navigation-in-react-native-organizing-properly)